# How to get the respective value from a multiple column based on the given value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in mysql as follows

```
id  slab1     slab2     slab3
1   200-500   600-800   900-100
```

my given value for search is 250

how to find the corresponding column value, based on the given no. in mysql

My expected output will be is 200-500

Comment: you should have not saved it delimited with dashes

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: my expected output will be 200-500 @Nick

Comment: use between keyword

Comment: @Kevin actually dashes are not problem. i need a clue that fetch the corresponding value based on the given no. If you knew you can use without answer. I need a clue

Comment: @Atk i have a single value, how to use the between.

Comment: You have to first split the data and then use between

Comment: or you could devise something like this instead http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/006987/4

Comment: explode the column data by "-" and then use between to get the expected output

Comment: This kind of problem is highly symptomatic of poor schema design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will give you the column name and range for a given search value (in this case 250):

```
SELECT slab_num, slab
FROM (
  SELECT 'slab1' AS slab_num, slab1 AS slab, 
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(slab1, '-', 1) AS low,
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(slab1, '-', -1) AS high
  FROM slabs
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'slab2', slab2, 
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(slab2, '-', 1),
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(slab2, '-', -1)
  FROM slabs
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'slab3', slab3, 
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(slab3, '-', 1),
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(slab3, '-', -1)
  FROM slabs
) s
WHERE 250 BETWEEN low AND high
```

Output

```
slab_num    slab
slab1       200-500
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/598b05/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select case when (select 250) > 200 and (select 250) < 500 then slab1 
when (select 250) > 600 and (select 250) < 800 then slab2 
when (select 250) > 900 and (select 250) < 1000 then slab3 end as slab from test;
```

Replace 250 with given value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 250 BETWEEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(slab1,'-',1) AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(slab1,'-',-1) THEN slab1
            WHEN 250 BETWEEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(slab2,'-',1) AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(slab2,'-',-1) THEN slab2
            WHEN 250 BETWEEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(slab3,'-',1) AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(slab3,'-',-1) THEN slab3 
            ELSE 'None' END AS checking 
FROM mytable;
```

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dsFBJb5tzHTTv4rSG5LGuw/1

Or maybe you can set the search value in a variable so you only need to chage the value in one place:

```
SET @val := 250;

SELECT CASE WHEN @val BETWEEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(slab1,'-',1) AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(slab1,'-',-1) THEN slab1
            WHEN @val BETWEEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(slab2,'-',1) AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(slab2,'-',-1) THEN slab2
            WHEN @val BETWEEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(slab3,'-',1) AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(slab3,'-',-1) THEN slab3 
            ELSE 'None' END AS checking 
FROM mytable;
```